# How to hide element outside of ng-controller from controller js in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this code that shows contents outside of the ng-controller.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group companyName">
    <!-- buttons -->
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-md-12 col-sm-12" ng-controller="TopicsCtrl">
    <div class="faq-breadcrumbs">
        <!-- contents -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('sample').controller('TopicsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    //how to hide first div?
};
```

The top div is inside the site's header, so it is shown in all pages of the site. The second div is only shown if I am in the FAQ page. Now I don't want the first div to show on the header whenever I am in the FAQ page. How can this be done? Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular way to do this would be to create a directive that manipulates the DOM and will hide the element on the page when the route is on the FAQ page.  In order to do this you will have to increase the scope of your app to include the header.

If you can't do that, I would suggest just going the javascript/jquery way and hiding the companyName div when the location is at faq. Something like this could work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.pathname == 'faq'){
        $('.companyName').css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

This solution does pose the problem of potentially showing information before the document is completely loaded.